# How to make a keras prediction from a trained model

Tags: keras

I have a trained model for predicting the property of an image and have some images where the property is unknown. This is what I was training my model to predict for. I'm confused about the dimensions needed for the data to be predicted. When using the `model.predict_classes()`, I get an error saying that it expects a 4D array. After reshaping it, it says that it expects an array with 3 dimensions.

I think I am misunderstanding the error in some way.

Comment: If you are doing image classification, the input shape must be ( batch_size , height , width , num_channels )